# What is the "8900" that the FAA uses for guidance?

Tags: faa-regulations, faa

The 8900 is sometimes quoted as a reference when trying to determine FAA policies.

What exactly is it and where can it be found?  Is it regulatory in nature?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The **Flight Standards Information Management System**, created by [FAA Order 8900.1](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/8900.1.pdf), is the source of all information relating to aviation safety inspector job tasks.  It's about 8,000 pages worth of (non-regulatory) guidance and policy helping FAA Inspectors to do their job properly.

It's an electronic-only document, which can be found at [fsims.faa.gov](http://fsims.faa.gov/), or by visiting the [FAA homepage](https://www.faa.gov/) and entering "8900" in the search box at the top right.

There's all kinds of good stuff in there, such as:

- [How do I give a practical test for a CFI applicant with a sport pilot rating?](http://fsims.faa.gov/PICDetail.aspx?docId=8900.1,Vol.5,Ch2,Sec12)
- [How do I perform field approval of a major repair or alteration?](http://fsims.faa.gov/PICDetail.aspx?docId=8900.1,Vol.4,Ch9,Sec1)
- [How do I do a ramp inspection?](http://fsims.faa.gov/PICDetail.aspx?docId=8900.1,Vol.6,Ch1,Sec4)

*And lots more!*

FSIMS is open to the general public - if you want to know what an inspector does day in and day out (or what to expect when you meet one), FSIMS is the one-stop-shopping location for the answers to all your questions.